# Unable to create vnet peering on azure using terraform and csv data

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template

```
Dear Friends,

We are unable to create a Virtual network gateway using the below configuration.
1. We are able to create vnet,subnets and pering using the csv file,but when we try to create multiple subnets using csv data it was showing duplicate error.2. Because of the duplicate error we have created a new two Gateway subnet  manually using azure portal.
```

3.After this we have tried using the data block and refernce its subnet id inside the resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" block  but its failing with error and after removing the data block we are seeing below error.
4.While using data it was saying its not a value.

Can someone please post your suggestions here.

```
 Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 152, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnet-gateway-name":
│  152:     subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.GatewaySubnet].id #data.azurerm_subnet.GatewaySubnet.id #azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.GatewaySubnet].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_subnet.subnet is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.value.GatewaySubnet is "GatewaySubnet"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
   
 csv file:

#cat rg_name.csv
azureuser@aztfserver:~/newcsv$ cat rg_name.csv
resource_group_name,location,vnet_name,vnet_address_space,subnet_name,subnet_address_space,remote_vnet,natpip_name,natgateway_name,vnetgatewaypip_name,vnetgateway_name,GatewaySubnet
rg-ScriptTest-eus-001,East US,vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001,10.0.0.0/16,subnet1,10.0.1.0/26,vnet-ScriptTest-wus-001,pip-natgw-eus-001,gw-NAT-test-eus-001,pip-vpngw-test-eus-001,vpngw-test-eus-001,GatewaySubnet
rg-ScriptTest-wus-001,West US,vnet-ScriptTest-wus-001,11.0.0.0/16,subnet2,11.0.1.0/26,vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001,pip-natgw-wus-001,gw-NAT-test-wus-001,pip-vpngw-test-wus-001,vpngw-test-wus-001,GatewaySubnet

Terraform code :

   locals {
  vnet_config = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/rg_name.csv"))
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.resource_group_name => v }
  name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnet_name => v }
  name                = each.value.vnet_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  address_space       = [each.value.vnet_address_space]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  name                = each.value.subnet_name
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.subnet_address_space]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}
/*
data "azurerm_subnet"  "GatewaySubnet" {
   name = "GatewaySubnet"
   resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.rg[each.key]
   virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.key]
}
*/



# Assuming that the remote_vnet column in your CSV contains the name of the remote vnet
# and that the remote vnets are within the same subscription and resource group as the local vnets.
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "vnet_peering" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.remote_vnet}" => v }

  name                      = "peer-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name       = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name      = each.value.vnet_name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.value.remote_vnet].id

  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.vnet,
    azurerm_subnet.subnet
  ]

}

#Public IP

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "natpipname" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.natpip_name => v }
  name                = each.value.natpip_name
  resource_group_name    = each.value.resource_group_name
  location               = each.value.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  depends_on          = [azurerm_nat_gateway.natgateway,]
}


#Natgateway
resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "natgateway" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.natgateway_name => v }
  name                    = each.value.natgateway_name
  location                = each.value.location
  resource_group_name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}

# Associate NAT Gateway with Public IP
resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "natpipassosciation_name" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.natgateway_name => v }
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.natgateway[each.value.natgateway_name].id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.natpipname[each.value.natpip_name].id
  depends_on          = [azurerm_nat_gateway.natgateway,azurerm_public_ip.natpipname]
}



# Associate NAT Gateway with Subnet


resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "subnet_natgateway" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  #subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.key].id
  subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.subnet["${each.value.vnet_name}-${each.value.subnet_name}"].id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.natgateway[each.value.natgateway_name].id
  depends_on          = [azurerm_nat_gateway.natgateway]
}


#Vnet Gateways:
#Manages a Virtual Network Gateway to establish secure, cross-premises connectivity.
#Please be aware that provisioning a Virtual Network Gateway takes a long time (between 30 minutes and 1 hour)

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vnetgatewaypipname" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnetgatewaypip_name => v }
  name                = each.value.vnetgatewaypip_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  allocation_method = "Dynamic"
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnet-gateway-name" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnetgateway_name => v }
#  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  name                = each.value.vnetgateway_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"

  ip_configuration {
    #for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnetgwconfig => v }
    #name                          = each.value.vnetgwconfig_name
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.vnetgatewaypipname[each.value.vnetgatewaypip_name].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.GatewaySubnet].id #data.azurerm_subnet.GatewaySubnet.id #azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.GatewaySubnet].id
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_public_ip.vnetgatewaypipname]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kpRz.png)

Comment: Try Updating the remote_virtual_network_id in your Terraform code to dynamically reference the correct remote VNet ID, and ensure the remote VNet exists before peering.
@SharanKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to create vnet peering on azure using terraform and csv data and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

There is a problem with the Azure Virtual Network Peering configuration. The error indicates that the `remote_virtual_network_id` cannot be located. This could be because the ID that you are using in the `azurerm_virtual_network_peering` resource is malformed or the remote virtual network does not exist.

You need to follow few steps to achieve this configuration.

1. Before creating the peering, make sure that the remote virtual networks (`vnet-ScriptTest-wus-002` and `vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001`) are already created. To ensure that the peering resource depends on the remote VNet, you may have to add a `depends_on` attribute.
2. You need to fetch the `remote_virtual_network_id` dynamically instead of hardcoding the subscription ID and using a placeholder for the resource group name. To do this, you can query Azure using the VNet's name and resource group, which should be the same as what you have in your CSV file. This will give you the ID of the remote VNet.

***rg_name.csv***

```
subscription_name,subscriptionID,resource_group_name,location,vnet_name,vnet_address_space,subnet_name,subnet_address_space,remote_vnet

Subscription_Name,Subscription_ID,rgvk-ScriptTest-eus-001,East US,vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001,10.0.0.0/16,subnet1,10.0.1.0/26,vnet-ScriptTest-wus-002

Subscription_Name,Subscription_ID,rgvk-ScriptTest-wus-002,West US,vnet-ScriptTest-wus-002,11.0.0.0/16,subnet2,11.0.1.0/26,vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001
```

***My Configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  vnet_config = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/rg_name.csv"))
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.resource_group_name => v }
  name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnet_name => v }
  name                = each.value.vnet_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  address_space       = [each.value.vnet_address_space]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  name                = each.value.subnet_name
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.subnet_address_space]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}


# Assuming that the remote_vnet column in your CSV contains the name of the remote vnet
# and that the remote vnets are within the same subscription and resource group as the local vnets.
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "vnet_peering" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.remote_vnet}" => v }

  name                      = "peer-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name       = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name      = each.value.vnet_name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.value.remote_vnet].id

  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.vnet,
    azurerm_subnet.subnet
  ]


}
```

***Deployment Succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks vinay for your inputs and time , have tried the code and it is working as expected. Could you please explain this line here:
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }

Comment: It tells Terraform to create a separate azurerm_subnet resource for each combination of virtual network and subnet defined in the local.vnet_config list. Each instance of the subnet resource is uniquely identified by a key constructed from its virtual network and subnet names, and it is configured according to the details specified in the corresponding item from the local.vnet_config list @sharankumar

Comment: Hi Vinay have a small query here I am unable to fetch the subnet id details using this format.
│   on main.tf line 134, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnetgateway_name":
│  134:     subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.subnet_name].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_subnet.subnet is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.value.subnet_name is "subnet1"

Comment: resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnetgateway_name" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnetgateway_name => v }
  name = each.value.vnetgateway_name
  location                = each.value.location
  resource_group_name     = each.value.resource_grou
  ip_configuration {
    for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vnetgatewaypipname[each.value.vnetgatewaypip_name].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.key].id

Comment: try this resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  ...
}
once @sharankumar

Comment: Yesits working and creating subnets, But when is this correct way to get subnetid
resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "subnet_natgateway" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.key].id

Comment: When trying to use public_ip resource for Nat gateway and vnet gateay I  am seeing this error

 Error: Cycle: azurerm_virtual_network_gateway.vnetgateway_name, azurerm_public_ip.vnetgatewaypipname

Comment: To fix the cycle error between your azurerm_virtual_network_gateway and azurerm_public_ip, make sure there are no dependencies from the public IP pointing back to the gateway. Also, ensure the public IP is established before you reference it in the gateway configuration. Carefully review your Terraform setup to eliminate any inadvertent dependencies that could lead to this issue.

Comment: Hi Vinay, i am unable to create the vnet gateway for some reason it throwing an error  for subnet id , i have used a data block to reference it in line 150  but its throwing error
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
╷
│ Error: expected ip_configuration.0.subnet_id to reference a gateway subnet with name GatewaySubnet
│
│   with azurerm_virtual_network_gateway.vnet-gateway-name["vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001-subnet1"],
│   on main.tf line 150, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnet-gateway-name":
│  150:     subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.key].id

Comment: resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vnetgatewaypipname" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnetgatewaypip_name => v }
  name                = each.value.vnetgatewaypip_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name

  allocation_method = "Dynamic"
}

Comment: resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnet-gateway-name" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnetgateway_name => v }
#  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  name                = each.value.vnetgateway_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"

Comment: edit your question @sharankumar you are making it more difficult to understand by the way you are sharing this in comments please edit the question along with the error I will address the issue

Comment: Hi vinay Sorry for the inconvenience the issue is I am unable to create Virtual network gateway
│ Error: Invalid index
│   on main.tf line 150, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vnet-gateway-name":
│  150:     subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.subnet_name].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_subnet.subnet is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.value.subnet_name is "subnet2"
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
reference
subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.value.subnet_name].id

Comment: there is an option to edit your question please update the code you tried till now along with the blocker info @sharankumar

Comment: Hi Vinay Have updated the  question, Thanks for your support. Awaiting for your feedback

Comment: # For vnet peering, ensure 'remote_vnet' in CSV matches vnet keys:
remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.value.remote_vnet].id
# Correct subnet reference in vnet gateway to use composite key:
subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet["${each.value.vnet_name}-${each.value.subnet_name}"].id
Make sure remote_vnet names correspond to vnet_name keys. For subnets, use vnet_name-subnet_name as the key.

try updating this configuration changes @sharankumar

Comment: Sure will test it , Thanks for the update  Vinay.

Comment: Hi Vinay ,subnet id is working as of now, but when trying to created gateway subnet we are facing an issue, I have update the actual post content  could you or anyone help me on this please.

Comment: @sharankumar please post a new follow-up query so that I can provide you more detailed solution.